# Assign random ngModel to directive

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to assign a random string to ngModel. But I can't even seem to assign a regular string to it. In the code below, I'm trying to change the ngModel to "new", but in chrome, it's still showing me that the ngModel is "placeholder". What am I doing wrong?

```
app.directive("page", function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<div ng-model="placeholder"></div>',

        controller: function ($scope, $element) {
            $scope.placeholder = "new";
        }
}});
```

The plain div tag was just an example. What I actually have is a content editable div that I've bound to a textarea with a contenteditable directive. I made a button to allow me to add as many of these directives as I want, but when I add this directive, I'd like a new ng-model for each one, because that's what I'm using to save the content of each content editable div to a file.

---

This is the full example in case it might help someone else. I put the addPage directive to a button, which, when clicked, appends a new content editable div (which I'm calling a page). There is one more directive that I didn't include (contenteditable) because I got it from the bottom of the docs over [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)

```
app.directive("addPage", function($compile){
    return function(scope, element, attrs){
        element.bind("click", function(){           angular.element(document.getElementById('container')).append($compile('<page></page>')(scope));
        });
    };
});

app.directive("page", function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        // template: '<div class="page" contenteditable strip-br="true" ng-model="chapter"></div>',
        template: function (elem, attr) {
            var test="chapter.two"; //in reality, I will generate a random string to keep these divs unique
            return '<div class="page" contenteditable strip-br="true" ng-model=' + test  +'></div>'
        }
}});
```

In my controller, I have this object that is used to store all the ng-model content

```
$scope.chapter = {};
```

Comment: You would have to use interpolation for that `ng-model="{{placeholder}}"`. But it look weird to me? `ng-model` is used with input. What are you trying?

Comment: The div tag was just an example. What I actually have is a content editable div that I've bound to a textarea with a contenteditable directive. I made a button to allow me to add as many of these directives as I want, but when I add this directive, I'd like a new ng-model for each one.

Comment: I tried {{placeholder}} but I get a parse syntax error.

Comment: `ng-model` works with an input control - it is next to meaningless on a `<div>`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I added some more context to the question, does it make sense?

Comment: @thatandrey, can you complete the question with the button that adds more directives? I think you're doing something weird here with a random expression for each `ng-model`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are approaching this a bit backwards. Starting with the model, you'd need an array to keep the values from all of the inputs / contenteditables.

```
.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope){
   $scope.data = [{v: ""}]; // first element

   $scope.addContentEditable = function(){
      $scope.data.push({v: ""});
   };
})
```

Then, you can bind to each element of that array easily, and add elements at will:

```
<button ng-click="addContentEditable()">Add</button>
<div ng-repeat="item in data" ng-model="item.v" contenteditable></div>
```

I'm not sure exactly how the `page` directive needs to be used here, but one way or another, the approach is the same as above.

Comment: totally agree...all the random strings and X-Y issues made it tricky to figure out the full needs. This approach is pretty typical and is the simplest

Comment: I think that's the better approach. I couldn't find this typical approach anywhere so I hacked together my own, I'll try to migrate over to this as soon as I can. Thanks!

Comment: Technically the other answer answered my original question, but I really like this too! The empty string that you have in $scope.data- should I make those random strings if I want to save and then load ng-model data? ..actually wait, the ng-model is "item.v", so all the data is in the "item" variable, right?

Comment: @thatandrey, each contenteditable text will be stored in the `v` property of each element (yes, the iteration-local `item` variable) of the `data` array. And, there is nothing special about this approach - it is really a typical approach to things - you just need to start from the data - the View will follow.

Comment: Thanks, and one last question, if I save the data array, and then restore it (assign it to  `$scope.data`) when the user clicks a "load" button, then the saved content editable divs should appear on the page automatically?

Comment: @NewDev I switched to your approach and it works for the most part, but I can't seem to initialize the  contenteditable divs by filling in the v property in $scope.data. This also means that I can't load saved data, even though I can save it correctly. It's pretty weird, so I made a new question here, can you help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30047613/ng-model-inside-ng-repeat-is-conflicting-with-scope-model-somehow-isnt-updatin

Comment: @thatandrey, you should accept the answer that best helped you. I actually think it would be a disservice to future visitors if the accepted answer is not what you ended up using... It is up to you, of course (neither I nor charlietfl would miss the 15 rep points) - but I have a feeling that charlietfl would even want to delete his, but can't, since it's the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to pass a string in you could use attributes and `template(fn)`

HTML

```
<div page="new">
```

Directive

```
app.directive("page", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: function (elem, attr) {
            return '<div ng-model="' + attr.page + '"></div>';
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, the thing is, I won't have any such html on my page. I just have a button that adds the page directive. Can I just put the logic to create a random string inside `template(fn)`?

Comment: what will you do with a random string anyway? How will you know what to look for in controller? ...but yes you could create it in the function. You should also always have a dot in `ng-model` ...to allow for object inheritance. Primitves won't 2 way bind in child scopes

Comment: assigning `ng-model` to div is bad practice..it should be there only with input, select, textarea only

Comment: @pankajparkar it is a conteneditable and is perfectly acceptable for that. If you have an alternative to bind a contentediable feel free to add your solution. It is also commonly used in directives with isolate scopes to be able to pass to form controls by using `require:'^ngModel`

Comment: @charlietfl thats my bad..I didn't read the question properly

Comment: I guess that's what I'm still trying to determine. Since I'm able to create as many of these content editable divs as I want, the only way I could come up with to keep them unique was to assign a random ng-model to them. Although your solution isn't the exact one I'm using (since I can't use the html part), the template function worked to add a random ng-model. Now my divs are being saved, and I just have to figure out a way to load them back to the page.

Comment: Perhaps you need an indexing system so you can keep track in controller