# ng model inside ng repeat is conflicting with scope model somehow, isn't updating

Tags: angularjs

I'm not sure exactly what the issue is, but something weird is going on. I have a contenteditable directive that lets me assign an ng-model to a div (which I got from the some angular documentation), which I'm using to save the changes made in the div.

In my html, I have: (I'm linking the textarea to the div so I can confirm the binding is working)

```
<button ng-click="addPage()">Add Page</button>

<div ng-repeat-start="item in book" ng-model="item.v" contenteditable></div>
<textarea ng-model="item.v" ng-repeat-end></textarea>
```

The problem is that the ng-repeat produces an empty div/textarea even though I specified a base model in my controller:

```
  $scope.book = [{v: "asd", t: "test"}];
  $scope.addPage = function(){
     $scope.book.push({v: "", t: "test"});
  };
```

Shouldn't the div be loaded with the value "asd"? The curious thing is when I use the console log to see `$scope.book`, It has the correct value for the `t` property, but not the`v` property. When I change the html code from `item.v` to `item.t`, then the reverse happens in the console log, and it's the "t" property that gets overwritten.

It's almost as if `$scope.book` is being overwritten by the ng-repeat. After the page has loaded, I can add as many of these divs as I want, type in them, and then when I check the console log, there are being saved to $scope.book correctly. But something seems to be happening initially.. Any help?

---

**Solution** 
As pointed out in the comments, the problem was with the content editable directive, which you can see in action over [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/0PhHIklxZvFS3SgI4pHH?p=preview). Specifically, I don't know why exactly and I'd love to find out, but the error occurs here:

```
        read(); // initialize

        // Write data to the model
        function read() {
          var html = element.html();
          // When we clear the content editable the browser leaves a <br> behind
          // If strip-br attribute is provided then we strip this out
          if ( attrs.stripBr && html == '<br>' ) {
            html = '';
          }
          ngModel.$setViewValue(html);
        }
```

`$setViewValue` is overwriting the ngModel somehow, so all I had to do (as suggested by New Dev) was comment out the `read()` function and it works great now.

Comment: How did you implement the `contenteditable` directive? It's not supported out-of-the-box by Angular (I don't think) and so I presume you made it `require: "ngModel"` and could be overwriting the model there.

Comment: I used the directive from this plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/2C2JhaVvhf9ZFf1YvcYm?p=preview. I'll try to put my own plunker up right now.

Comment: So, it's quite clear why it overwrites your `ng-model` - as soon as its `link` function runs, it reads the underlying DOM html and does `$setViewValue`

Comment: Oh really is there anything I can do? Here's my plunk, but there's some kind of error and it doesn't seem to work > http://plnkr.co/edit/2C2JhaVvhf9ZFf1YvcYm?p=preview

Comment: Commenting out the `$setViewValue` allows me to load my saved content and the initial content, and the textarea is bound to the div, but the div is not bound to the textarea.

Comment: I think I'd comment out `read()` rather

Comment: Wow that seems to work great! Can you explain why for future reference? If you add this as an answer, I'll accept the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input directives - both built-in and custom - `require: "ngModel"`. That is to say that they use the `ngModel` pipeline to marshal data between the Model and the View through a pipe of `$formatters`, `$parsers` and `$validators`.

An input control (doesn't have to be `<input>`) would call `$setViewValue` when it detects that its "View" state has changed (typically a DOM interaction has happened, but could be for whatever reason - could be based on `$interval`).

An input control would also define `ngModel.$render` to render its DOM in response to a change coming from the Modal side.

And typically, the Model takes precedence over the View, because ultimately, the View should be driven by the Model (i.e. ViewModel).

This doesn't happen with your `contenteditable`. In fact, it calls `read()` to "initialize" based on its View data. Since it is empty, it sets (via `$setViewValue - something one would do when a user has interacted with the control) the ngModel-bound value to be empty.

Removing the call to `read()` fixes the issue.